# Why am i getting "missing right parenthesis" error when i try to LOG ERRORS when loading from an external table?

Tags: oracle, insert, errors, error-log

I've successfully created an error logging table

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_ERRLOG.create_error_log(
    dml_table_name  => 'enzyme',
    skip_unsupported => TRUE);
END;
/

desc ERR$_ENZYME;
```

```
Name            Null? Type           
--------------- ----- -------------- 
ORA_ERR_NUMBER$       NUMBER         
ORA_ERR_MESG$         VARCHAR2(2000) 
ORA_ERR_ROWID$        UROWID         
ORA_ERR_OPTYP$        VARCHAR2(2)    
ORA_ERR_TAG$          VARCHAR2(2000) 
ENZ_NAME              VARCHAR2(4000)
```

But i get an error when I try to run this query:

```
insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index ( enzyme ( enz_name ) ) */
into enzyme
SELECT enz_name FROM EXTERNAL ((
  construct_id NUMBER(10),
  n_term VARCHAR2 (50),
  enz_name VARCHAR2 (3),
  c_term VARCHAR2 (50),
  cpp VARCHAR2 (50),
  mutations VARCHAR2 (50),
  mw_kda NUMBER (7, 3))

    TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY data_to_input
    ACCESS PARAMETERS (
        RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
        skip 1
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL 
        ) 
    LOCATION ('CONSTRUCT.CSV')
    LOG ERRORS INTO ERR$_ENZYME ('INSERT') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED) ext
    where not exists (
        select * from enzyme e
        where e.enz_name = ext.enz_name
    );
```

```
Error at Command Line : 79 Column : 5
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Line 79 is the LOG ERRORS INTO line.

If i delete the `LOG ERRORS INTO ERR$_ENZYME ('INSERT')` part, this command functions perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that question. I learned two things I was unaware we did: the in-line EXTERNAL tables and the automatic error logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the DML error logging (`LOG ERRORS INTO ...`) part belongs to the outer insert, not the inline external table. Move it out from the inner part.

External tables have a different kind of error logging, another file can be specified with the `BADFILE` clause where the rows with errors are logged.

**Update:**

Something like this:

```
insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index ( enzyme ( enz_name ) ) */
into enzyme
SELECT enz_name FROM EXTERNAL ((
  construct_id NUMBER(10),
  n_term VARCHAR2 (50),
  enz_name VARCHAR2 (3),
  c_term VARCHAR2 (50),
  cpp VARCHAR2 (50),
  mutations VARCHAR2 (50),
  mw_kda NUMBER (7, 3))

    TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY data_to_input
    ACCESS PARAMETERS (
        RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
        skip 1
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL 
        ) 
    LOCATION ('CONSTRUCT.CSV')
    ) ext
    where not exists (
        select * from enzyme e
        where e.enz_name = ext.enz_name
    )
LOG ERRORS INTO ERR$_ENZYME ('INSERT') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but where do I move it to? Could you show me please? I've also tried using BADFILE, but the problem is that if there's a row that gets rejected, none of my rows will get inserted. ...although maybe that's not a HUGE problem. I wonder if it would be more convenient to have the errors logged in a txt file rather than a table.

Comment: @ellie-lumen Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and got ```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout
ORA-30653: reject limit reached``` But when i query the error table, there's nothing there. Weird. But. I thought about the idea of using badfiles, and I think badfiles would actually be sufficient for me. Still, I appreciate your answer because now I know where to put the LOG ERRORS statement!

Comment: @ellie-lumen `BADFILE` can be used to log errors while reading from the external table. E.g data that does not match the defined format. DML error logging can be used to log errors while inserting data. E.g a constraint or data type violation. That error comes from the reading of external table, DML error logging will not handle that.